# Fix listview's height to empty space

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm new with WPF and want to set the listview's height to the bottom of my frame. The listview's width ist already set with a fix value. The following code represents my DockPanel:

```
<DockPanel 
    Name="dp"
    Width="200" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0,5,0,5"/>
    <ListView Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=dp}" Background="Yellow" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
        <ListViewItem Content="foobar"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="foobar2"/>
    </ListView>
</DockPanel>
```

The first screenshot will show the current szenario:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLmi7.png

and the heigth shell strech to the height as it is shown in the next picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cc2Jg.png

Thanks a lot!

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
<Window>
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        </Menu>
        <DatePicker DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem>
                <StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
                        <ListView>
                        </ListView>
                    </DockPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Try this:

```
<Window>
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        </Menu>
        <DatePicker DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem>
                <StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem>
                <DockPanel>  <!-- instead of StackPanel -->
                    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                    </Grid>
                    <!-- can now get rid of this <DockPanel>  -->
                    <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
                    <ListView>
                    </ListView>
                </DockPanel>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` on the `ListView` element. The same is true for `HorizontalAlignment` if you need to do the same horizontally.

```
<DockPanel 
    Name="dp"
    Width="200" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0,5,0,5"/>
    <ListView Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=dp}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Yellow" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
        <ListViewItem Content="foobar"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="foobar2"/>
    </ListView>
</DockPanel>
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751709(v=vs.110).aspx for more information.

---

I have tested your code using `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"`, and I am getting your desired result:

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel 
    Name="dp"
    Width="200" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0,5,0,5"/>
    <ListView Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=dp}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Yellow" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
        <ListViewItem Content="foobar"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="foobar2"/>
    </ListView>
</DockPanel> 
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

If you cannot get the `VerticalAlignment` to work properly, we can bind the `ActualHeight` of an element to its ancestor element. So, add this to your ListView:

```
Height="{ Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={ RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={ x:Type Window } } }"
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I've tried your solution, but the behavior is not as expected. Please have a look at my second screenshot. There you can see where the listview's height shell align.

Comment: @aquastar give me a moment while I open a project to test this.

Comment: @aquastar I am updating my answer.

Comment: @aquastar Since I've got your desired result working on my end, I'm not too sure what to suggest. Perhaps it's a bug in your version of Visual Studio, or maybe there's some other code you've got in there that's preventing it from filling up the rest of the space. Can you post your full XAML code?

Comment: @aquastar I am updating my answer with an alternative solution.

Comment: Of course: http://pastebin.com/KbZnHFLm Don't wonder about the strange design. :D
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Thanks, this works. Unfortunately the listview's height now is stretching endless. I just want to set the height to the main frame's end and if I resize the main frame, it shall adjust the listview's height.

Comment: The last item in a `DockPanel` should size to fill the remaining space. That means you shouldn't need to set the `VerticalAlignment` or the `Height`. Try removing the `VerticalAlignment` and `DockPanel.Dock` assignments for the `ListView`.

Comment: @StevenRands but it isn't doing that.

Comment: @StevenRands Thanks! What do you mean with "last item should size to fill"?

Comment: @RǢF Sorry, you commented before I edited! You need to remove the `DockPanel.Dock` assignment for the `ListView`.

Comment: @StevenRands correction: It does that on my end, but not aquastar's.

Comment: @aquastar  In a `DockPanel`, the last item will be sized by the panel to fill any remaining space. In your case, you have 2 items in your panel. You are docking the `TextBox` to the top. If you do not specify a `DockPanel.Dock` value for the `ListView`, then the panel will automatically size that control to take up the remaining space in the panel that is not used by the `TextBox`.

Comment: @StevenRands Thanks! I've updated my code as you can see at the paste (http://pastebin.com/EHr92RyZ). But it also doesn't work, where is my error located? It doesn't stretch to the bottom.

Comment: @aquastar  What control is your `DockPanel` hosted within? Can you update your Pastebin to include the full XAML for the `Window`? It could be that the parent control of the `DockPanel` is restricting its height.

Comment: @StevenRands http://pastebin.com/E30ZKKhS There you can see the current XAML Code. As you said I removed the DockPanel.Dock and the VerticalAlignment, but nethertheless it doesn't work.

Comment: @aquastar It's because you have your `DockPanel` inside a `StackPanel`. Try replacing the `StackPanel` with another `DockPanel`, then dock the `Grid` to the top. I've posted a separate answer.

Comment: Thanks, this works! I just replaced the StackPanel with the DockPanel. Is there a special reasion why this doesn't work with a StackPanel?

Comment: @aquastar  Glad I could help! In a vertical `StackPanel`, the child elements only take as much height as they need. So your `ListView` was sizing itself based on the height of the items within it. If you had put more items in the `ListView` then its height would have increased. To get "take as much room as is available" behaviour, you need to place the child element in something like a `Grid` or a `DockPanel`.

Comment: @Steve Do you want to post your own answer? I think this one should be deleted as the whole answer is wrong.

Comment: Perfect, guys - thanks!! Now i can go ahead. I will try to get the fitting situation for a StackPanel and for a DockPanel. Best regards! I think, you don't have to delete your post, it could be helpful for someone.

Comment: @RǢF Agreed with aquastar, I think it's useful to keep this answer also as it provides some context and shows how we got to a working solution